# SendGrid: Setting Env Variable not working

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, sendgrid

I'm creating a contact form for my website, and I'm trying to set the environmental variable for SendGrid, but it's not working.

I've tried `setx SENDGRID_API_KEY 'SG.myAPIKey'`, but when I go and run the code, it gives me the message `API key does not start with "SG.".

I have the following code, if it helps.

Thanks!

**App.js**

```
const express = require('express'); //Needed to launch server.
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors'); //Needed to disable sendgrid security.
const sendGrid = require('@sendGrid/mail'); //Access SendGrid library to send emails.

sendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

//sendGrid.setApiKey('SG.myAPIKey');
const app = express(); //Alias from the express function.

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.get('/api', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('API Status: Running');
});

app.post('/api/email', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const msg = {
        to: 'dyzhang@gatech.edu',
        from: req.body.email,
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.message
    }
    sendGrid.send(msg)
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error: ', err);
            res.status(401).json({
                success: false
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: ```process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY```  you have this in your env file ?

Comment: No? How do I create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First in your backend code structure create a `.env` file
And inside that declare the SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'YOUR API KEY'
this way you will be able to use the Sendgrid api key by

```
process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY
```

Comment: How create the `.env` file?

Comment: Just create a file and name it ```.env``` just like how you create a server.js or any other file inside your project

Answer (score 1):

As @jarivak suggested you need to create a `.env` file and use process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY however that is the recommended way.
If you want it for testing purposes, just change this line

```
sendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

to

```
sendGrid.setApiKey('YOUR API KEY');
```